# c# query builder remove filter

Tags: c#, filter, builder

I'm using a query builder in C# to filter data to a `DataGridView`.

I use the following code:

```
private void namefilter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //filters newreport on name
    this.newreportTableAdapter
        .namefilter(this.newreport_database.Onderhoud_Database, namefilter.Text);

    if (namefilter.Text == (""))
    {
        //remove filter. show al data in newreport.
    }
}
```

This code works fine for me, now I want to remove the filter when the combobox "namefilter" is set to "" anyone any idea regarding which code I need?

I've tried several codes. None of them work properly.

Regards

Peter